# Add items to listbox By thread in WPF using C#

Tags: wpf, listbox, thread-safety, dispatcher, begininvoke

I am using the code below, however it is causing my application to hang and I am unsure as to why. Would anyone be able to help me out here?

```
 void put_items() {
        listb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9000000; i++)
            {
                listb.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }));
            }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread mythread = new Thread(put_items);
        mythread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: The Dispatcher Action runs in the UI thread. So your background thread does virtually nothing.

Comment: thank's for information but How can take my code work fine?

Comment: Just out of interest, how does it behave if you add a smaller number, e.g. 10.  If that works then it's simply a performance issue, but if it still locks then you've got a more fundamental issue.

Comment: for information I use netframwork 3.5 not 4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update any UI controls this has to be done in the UI thread. By using the Dispatcher you force your application to execute the code within BeginInvoke-block to be executed on the ui thread.

Depending on how time consuming the work for one item in the for loop is, you could process a bunch of items (say 10 or 100) and then update the ui by using the dispatcher. Notice that each call of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke needs some time (maybe 500 ms).

Another way would be using an event aggregator see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx). Then your class containing the button click method would register to the event aggregator and in the thread you would just need the instance of the aggregator and call ea.Publish(new YourCustomEvent(yourItemToUpdateUI)).

This approach is really nice if your application is going to be complex.

Answer (score -1):

thank you but I think that code not work in netframwork 3.5 I think that I resolve By this code

```
public void put_items()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action (() =>
            {
               listb.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }));
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(put_items).Start();
    }
```

Comment: For .NET 3.5 you can install the Thread Parallel Library (TPL) from Microsoft. This will add the namespace System.Threading so you can use Tasks.